# LitElement EventListener() not update render() function

Tags: lit-element, lit

I have two Lit components that are at the same level but when the first component sends data to the second component using a dispatchEvent, the second component's render method is not updated.

html file

```html
<div>
    <test-input></test-input>
    <test-button></test-button>
</div>
```

javascript file

```js
export class TestButton extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    
    render() {
        return html`<button @click="${this._onClickHandler}">send</button>`;
    }

    _onClickHandler(event){
        let target = event.originalTarget;
        const options = {
            detail: { message: target.innerText },
            bubbles: true,
            composed: true
        }
        let buttonEvent = new CustomEvent('inputreceiver', options);
        this.dispatchEvent(buttonEvent);
    }
}
customElements.define('test-button', TestButton);


export class Display extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        content: {type: String}
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.content = '0.00';
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        window.addEventListener('inputreceiver', this._onChangeContent);
    }
    
    disconnectedCallback() {
        window.removeEventListener('inputreceiver', this._onChangeContent);
        super.disconnectedCallback();
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <p class="display">value: ${this.content}</p>
        `;
    }

    _onChangeContent(event){
        this.content = event.detail.message;
    }
}
customElements.define('test-input', Display);
```

I'm learning litJS and I want to send parameters from one component to another. But when I want to show the value obtained from the first component in the second component, the render method doesn't work for me.

Comment: your `this` in `_onChangeContent` is not pointing to where you are expecting it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `this` in your `_onChangeContent` function will be bound to `window` when adding your event listener.

Instead try defining `_onChangeContent` as an instance via an arrow function as recommended by [@Augustine Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19498660/augustine-kim):

```js
    _onChangeContent = (event) => {
        this.content = event.detail.message;
    }
```

or by passing an anonymous arrow function to your event listener. Note that this will stop you from being able to remove this event listener as no reference to the anonymous function is kept.

```js
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        window.addEventListener('inputreceiver', (e) => this._onChangeContent(e));
    }
```

This will ensure that `this` is bound to your component `test-input`.

Comment: Passing in the arrow function to `addEventListener` would bind `this` but now the function is anonymous so the `removeEventListener` won't work. I'd recommend creating a bound method in the constructor or using an arrow function when defining the method in the class field.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to reflect your recommendations.